# Using java variables as values in mysql insert statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I currently have two created methods, one named createDatabase which creates a mysql database, table and inserts values into that table. The second method collects data from the user and stores them in variables.

I'm struggling to know how it would be possible to pass the variables from the userInput method to the createDatabase method, And how to then use the variables as values for the insert statement.

Here is the createDatabase method

```
  public void createDatabase(){
    String data = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root&password=root";
    try {

         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(data);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connection made");

        int result = st.executeUpdate("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS TESTDATABASE");

        result = st.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE TESTDATABASE");

        result = st.executeUpdate("USE TESTDATABASE");

        result = st.executeUpdate(
                "CREATE TABLE testtable ("
                + "dex INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "name VARCHAR(40), "
                + "address1 VARCHAR(40), "
                + "address2 VARCHAR(40), "
                + "phone VARCHAR(20), "
                + "email VARCHAR(40))");
        result = st.executeUpdate(
                "INSERT INTO testtable(name, address1, address2, "
                + "phone, email) VALUES("
                + "'+name+', "
                + "'+address1+', "
                + "'+address2+', "
                + "'+phone+', "
                + "'+email+')"); 

        st.close();
        System.out.println("Database Created");
    }   catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error -- " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

The userInput method

```
public void userInput(){
    String name;
    String address1;
    String address2;
    String phone;
    String email;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Enter name");
    name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter first line of address");
    address1 = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter second line of address");
    address2 = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter phone number");
    phone = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter email address");
    email = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Details collected");

}
```

And main

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    TestDatabase test = new TestDatabase();
    test.userInput();
    test.createDatabase();

}
```

Any help and suggestions thanks!

Comment: You need to create a `User` object and populate it with your data. Then pass that instance of the `User` to the create database method. Finally, use a `PreparedStatement` to build your query, and set the values from the `User` object.

Answer (score 6):

To insert the record you should use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to protect against SQL injection:

```
    try{
        String sql = "INSERT INTO testtable(name, address1, address2,phone, email)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1,name);
        statement.setString(2,address1);
        statement.setString(3, address2);
        statement.setString(4, phone);
        statement.setString(5, email);
        statement.executeUpdate();
     }catch(SQLException e){

     }
```

Concatenating `String`s to form a SQL statement is never a good option, it creates a security vulnerability in your application and your boss will be jacked when its exploited.

Comment: And for the sake of readability, and to avoid problematic conversions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this in Java, I recommend following Object Oriented principles. Do not write Java code like is C. 
You can create a Person object that has the following fields:

```
    private String name;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
```

constructor

```
 Person(String name, String address1, String address2, String phone, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address1 = address1;
        this.address2 = address2;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
```

and getters like

```
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```

for each attribute.
After that in userInput write

```
return new Person(name, address1, address2, phone, email);
```

As a consequence the userInput now return an instance of Person.
Split the createDatabase method in 2 parts:
First method should handle the database creation
The second method should handle the insertion.
Example

```
public void insertInDatabase(Statement st, Person p) {
   // here you can use code that others have posted.
}
```

As a conclusion: **Please learn Java guidelines and principles and after that try to build something with it, because if you learn it stupid, you will use it stupid.** 
Sorry if any offense!

Comment: Apologies java is still very new to me and I did take a wild swing at making it work. Thank you for the breakdown.

Comment: Apologies are not for me. I want to give you the confidence to do things as they should be done. :D. I am sure you can do better after practice.

Comment: Absolutely. If no one tells me I will never learn to do it right. Thanks again :)